# Update tag generate multiple dialog instances in appendTo="@(body)" dialogs

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've the following error running on PF 5.1:

when I update a div that contains a

```
<p:dialog appendTo="@(body)" .... ></p:dialog>
```

It generates a duplicated dialog in the DOM

example

**main.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <h:form id="formGrowl">
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" showSummary="false" autoUpdate="true" />
            </h:form>
            <h:panelGroup id="mainPanel" style="background: #FFFFFF;" layout="block">

                <p:scrollPanel mode="native">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="padding: 1em;">

                    <p:commandButton value="Go to page with dialog"
                        action="#{myController.goToPageWithDialog}" update=":mainPanel"></p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGroup>
                    <c:if test="#{myController.renderPageWithDialog}">
                        <h:panelGroup>
                            <ui:include src="/pageWithDialog.xhtml"></ui:include>
                        </h:panelGroup>
                    </c:if>


        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**pageWithDialog.xhtml**

```
<h:body>
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form>
            <p:panel>
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                        <h:outputLabel value="Hello" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{myController.name}"></p:inputText>
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <p:panel>
                        <p:commandButton value="Back"
                            action="#{myController.goBack}" update=":mainPanel"></p:commandButton>

                        <p:commandButton value="#{diccionarioBean.msg['comunes.continuar']}" style="float:right;" process="@form"
                            oncomplete="PF('dialog').show();"></p:commandButton>
                    </p:panel>

                </p:panel>
            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
        <p:dialog id="idDialog" widgetVar="dialog" modal="true" appendTo="@(body)"
            header="Confirm" closable="false" width="400">
            <h:form>
                <h:panelGroup layout="block">
                    <strong>Are u sure?</strong>
                <p:separator />
                <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="text-align:center;">
                    <p:commandButton value="Yes" process="@this"
                        action="#{myController.action}" update=":formGrowl"></p:commandButton>
                    <p:commandButton value="No"
                        oncomplete="PF('dialog').hide();"></p:commandButton>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:form>
        </p:dialog>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

Clicking goToPageWithDialog -> Back Button -> goToPageWithDialog -> it renders dialog twice in the DOM. (And many times as you repeat this action)

Comment: what's your purpose for using appendTo="@(body)" ?

Comment: I want to append the dialog as a body child, this is a example It's not my real code, in code I've an accordionPanel -> tabs hierarchy and I don't want to include the dialog inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solve this problem,

I put a `styleClass="body-dialog"` on the dialog,

and execute the following js in the back button method

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("$('.body-dialog').destroy();");
```

I know that It's posible to do a better composition and include once in a separated form or panel and update only the another panel.

My question is about I thought the appendTo body tag must replace the another dialog if has the same id as the new one is trying to render in the DOM in 5.1 version as I saw in another post.

> If the area where JSF originally rendered the PrimeFaces component is
>   updated using JSF's AJAX feature, JSF will remove area to update from
>   the DOM, then render the component again, as it does not know it was
>   moved elsewhere. In old versions of PrimeFaces, this caused the
>   component to appear in the DOM twice (with the same id), which caused
>   problems with later submits. This was fixed for PrimeFaces 4.0 ( Issue
>   5636: Dialog appendToBody & dynamic doesn't remove the old dom element
>   ), but re-occurred in 5.0 (issue #367).

https://code.google.com/archive/p/primefaces/issues/5636